# JOptionPane Internal Dialog without title bar or close button?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I'm working on a game as a practice project. When it's first loaded, the user is prompted to login or create a new player. If the user selects to create a new player, what I want to happen is for the new-player-creation form to be displayed (the main game board is a `JDesktopPane`, and ideally, it would be in a `JPanel` on the top layer of it), and everything else pause until the user fills out and submits this form.

Since other user input tasks within the game are done with `JOptionPane.showInternalOptionDialog`, I figured this might do the job, as I'm looking for a `JPanel` that acts like a modal dialog. However, I want something that doesn't have a title bar or close `button`, just OK and Cancel buttons. Is there a way to show an internal dialog without these? Or some other way to have a `JPanel` act like a modal dialog?

Comment: You could take advantage of JXLayer as show [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982863/secure-desktop-mode-effect-for-java-application/12983564#12983564), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19799451/java-blocking-focus-from-jcomponent/19801009#19801009) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19324918/how-to-disable-all-components-in-a-jpanel/19328368#19328368) to block the main UI and the take advantage of the either the frames glass pane or layered pane to show you `JPanel`. This will "lock" the base UI and allow you to float a component on top of it

Comment: Take a look at [How to use Root Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) for more details...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the JDialog Class

This is an example, try to inspire from it :

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class BDialog extends JDialog {

    private JButton okBtn = new JButton("OK");
    private JButton cancelBtn = new JButton("Cancel");
    private JLabel messageLbl = new JLabel("This is a message");

    public BDialog() {
        super(new JFrame(), true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        setUndecorated(true);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        add(messageLbl);
        add(okBtn);
        add(cancelBtn);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BDialog();
    }

}
```

if that helps you make it solved please

Comment: Can this sort of thing be used in internal dialog? If so, it's probably what I'm looking for.

Comment: ofcourse that's why I write it for you. It needs a small modification to work great as a Dialog. If you want more help just ask me ^^

Comment: Okay, one more question. If I use one of these as a modal dialog, does it block SwingWorker threads in the background from running?

Comment: Can you show an example of how to call one as in internal dialog in a JDesktopPane? Would it need to be in a JOptionPane or JInternalFrame?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `JFrame` and use the `setUndecorated` method

```
JFrame myFrame = new JFrame("My Frame");
myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)       
myFrame.setBounds(10, 10, 300, 100);
myFrame.setUndecorated(true);
```

Then you can add a panel to this which would hold the buttons

Comment: Make it a modal dialog instead

Comment: Don't use set bounds. The frame should be packed so it is sized based on the components added to the dialog. You would also probably want to use the `setLocationRelativeTo(...)` method to position the dialog.

Comment: Thanks @camickr, i always thought `setBounds` was used to specify the size of the frame and place it. Is it not the case (and why)? If not when is this function supposed to be used ?

Comment: It can be used, but there are better API's to use to you don't have to make up magic numbers. The frame should be packed to give the frame a proper size based on the preferred size of components added to the frame. Then in the case of a frame you would use `setLocationByPlatform()` to let the OS determine where to display the frame. In the case of a popup dialog you probably want it centered relative the the existing frame so you would use `setLocationRelativeTo(...)`.